# Command line arguments not read in intellij, java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to to simply read the input of a user in my program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class My_Counter {

public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner my_scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("waiting for your number: \n");

    int num2 = my_scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(num2);
}
}
```

Then I go to Run -» Edit Configurations -» and add in field "program arguments" one number. And then when I press run configuration, the program just returns:

```
waiting for your numbers:
```

I have checked in the web already, but I cannot find anyone having the issue as me, it seemed that it has to work like this?? Or am I missing something? I am using the IDE on the newest Ubuntu version.

Comment: You need to enter a number for the program to read.

Comment: program arguments is different from standard input. program arguments is the argument `String[] args` in the `main` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line arguments are stored as *Strings* in the `String[] args` array of your main method.

You're not accessing the array but instead open up a Scanner which reads userinputs from the console **during runtime**. Also `Scanner#nextInt` is a **blocking** operation. Which means the program is 'suspended' until an input occurs from the underlying `InputStream` (`System.in` / stdin in this case).

In short: You've not accessed command line arguments but rather user input.

Try to input any number between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` after the "waiting for your number" prompt and it will echo the entered value.

To achiev your intended implementation you can go with something as follows:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  System.out.println( Integer.parseInt( args[0] ) );
}
```

Comment: Ohh ok, now I understand what I have mixed up. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. So just to clarify if I got everything correct: If I want to have command line arguments - so by beginning of the program, I retrieve them from String[] args, and if I want that during runtime, some other choices may be set by the user,  then I use the Scanner class?

Comment: @malajedala That is correct. `System.in` is the [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) representation of the so called _standard input stream_ (also commonly known as stdin)  which is directly connected to the console and can be read by any class which handles IO operations based on a stream. Command line arguments are values set when your programm is executed / started. Example: `$ java MyMainClass 2018` with 2018 being the first argument stored at `args[0]` (as a `String`) .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the number from the command line arguments, e.g., when you run  `java -jar <my-class-compiled>.jar 15` or in your IDE (in order to pass the number `15` to your program) you will have to retrieve that number like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String numberAsString = args[0]; // Will be "15"
   try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
   } catch (Exception e) { // Manage a possible exception
        System.out.println("The argument is not a valid Integer");
   }
   // Do your stuff...
}
```

In the other hand, if you want to pass a number on execution time, like a prompt, you will have to use `Scanner.nextInt`, i.e.: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm